# Late 2009 Macbook, El Capitan, how to rotate display? (it's not on settings)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, macos, screen, settings

I have a MacBook (13-inch, Late 2009) with El Capitan 10.11.6, The displays setting panel doesn't show a control to rotate it (as does my mac mini with Sierra)
Is there an alternative way or 3rd party software that could do this?

Answer (score 1):

The display settings panel has to be opened with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd> (+ clicking on the display panel icon)

Comment: Lol who downvoted my own answer which is exactly what I did to solve the problem I had in the first place?